# What's the point of the tree of life staying in Eden after Adam's fall?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, trees, gan-eden

> "*He drove the man out, and stationed east of the garden of Eden the cherubim and the fiery ever-turning sword, to guard the way to the tree of life*" [Genesis.3.24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.3.24?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)

The tree was left in Eden and protected by swords, but what for? Nobody could reach it, and by the time humanity returns to Eden the tree's irrelevant.

Comment: **Mishlei 11:30** - "The fruit of a righteous man is the tree of life, and the wise man acquires souls." ( פְּֽרִי־צַ֖דִּיק עֵ֣ץ חַיִּ֑ים וְלֹקֵ֖חַ נְפָשׁ֣וֹת חָכָֽם )